# Drupal 6 Feeds: admin/build/feeds empty importers

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I have a Drupal production site setup on ec2 dedicated server.

Following are the main settings:

Drupal: 6.16 MySQL: 5.1.57 PHP: 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17 Memory Limit: 256M Webserver: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) jQuery UI: 1.8 jQuery Update: 1.3.2

ctools: 6.x-1.9

Feeds: 6.x-1.0-beta12 Feeds Admin UI: 6.x-1.0-beta12 Feeds Fast News: 6.x-1.0-beta12 Feeds Import: 6.x-1.0-beta12 Feeds News: 6.x-1.0-beta12

The problem is that if I go to admin/build/feeds, the importers list is empty. When I flush the cache (admin_menu/flush-cache), the list reappears, but after navigating different site pages, when I revisit the admin/build/feeds, the importers list is empty again.

The same happens with the Import tab at the feed node pages (I am using feed as the source content type).

I have tried the following:

- Explicitly clear the cache using Drupal's cache functions
- Modify the feeds_importer_load_all function to set the required ctools static variables.
- Increased PHP memory limit to 512MB
- Completely disable the cache.
- Explicitly disable the cache with $GLOBALS['conf']['cache'] = FALSE; in hook_init
- And a few other patches as well

```
$cache = &ctools_static(FUNCTION); 
$cached_database = &ctools_static('ctools_export_load_object_all');
```

in function ctools_export_load_object are always empty and blank schema is returned.

None of above is solving the problem.

Does any one has experienced any similar scenario or knows what can be wrong with it? Appreciate the assistance in the matter.